# Why io.collection.ImageCollection behaves differently when looping and printing?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have the following script that reads the names of images in a given folder as follows :

```
pictures = io.collection.ImageCollection(IMAGE_DIRECTORY+'/'+'*.png')
```

when I print '*pictures*', I get the list of items as follows :

['D:/Python/1_1_9.png', 'D:/Python/1_2_9.png', 'D:/Python/1_3_9.png', 'D:/Python/1_4_9.png' ....]

However, when I loop the list to read individual list items, I get image arrays instead of image names. Why is that ?

```
for pic in pictures:
    print(pic)

[[[208 208 208]
  [211 211 211]
  [213 213 213]
  ...
  [204 204 204]
  [204 204 204]
  [220 220 220]]

 [[212 212 212]
  [207 207 207]
  [217 217 217]
  ...
```

Comment: When you `print(pictures)`, that calls the `__str__` or `__repr__` method to convert to a string.  When you do `from pic in pictures:`, that uses the iterator interface.  These are just design decisions by the autior.

Comment: wow, that's new to me. I am also new to Python ..... so, how can I read the names ? is that not possible? I could get the names using  'listdir' but I thought this is elegant....

Comment: finally found the way....should use 'files' method as follows: for pic in pictures.files:
    print(pic)